# Vuetify validation rules for string numeric combination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to determine how to use Vuetify validation to ensure the rules (using :rules tag on a v-text-field) meet this format:

AB-12345678 (first two characters are letters followed by hyphen then 8 digit number)

I am struggling to do this without using CharAt but I assume there is a cleaner and simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use regex

```
<v-text-field
  :rules="[v => /^[A-Z]{2}-\d{8}$/gm.test(v)]"
/>
```

It depends on exactly what you want but this regex is doing:

- `^` match start of line
- `[A-Z]{2}` match exactly 2 uppercase characters

  - Use `[A-Za-z]{2}` if upper/lowercase doesn't matter
- `-` match a dash
- `\d{8}` match 8 digits
- `$` match end of line
- `gm` at the end are flags for the regex

[Here's a page to test it](https://regex101.com/r/BWE8GG/1)

Comment: This answer provides each component and its purpose. I feel as though it has helped me gain a much better understanding of regex and its use in vuetify validation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex to check vailation

regex rule: **[A-B]{2}-[0-9]{8}**

check the code

```
<template>   
  <v-text-field
      :rules="customRule"
  />
</template>

<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    customRule() {
      return [
        v => /[A-B]{2}\-[0-9]{8}/.test(v) || "rule is not valid"
      ],
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors here, seems that `emailRules` (or `customRule`?) should be a computed property. A function should not be part of the component state...

Comment: I've fixed wrong naming. But CustomRule should be added in data .. not computed as written in Vuetify documentation

Comment: Where in the vuetify docs says that? A computed property works here perfectly well. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-text-field/prop-validation.vue

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Regular Expressions. Something like : `^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{8}$` should work.

To use Regex in javascript, you should refer to the [Mozilla developers docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

It looks like this :

```js
const paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. It barked.';
const regex = /[A-Z]/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
// expected output: Array ["T", "I"]
```